# Cannot authorise a salesforce org in fedora 31. Local host fails to respond

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, unauthorized-endpoint

This started happening just today.  In the past, I had no issues connecting to hosts.  But now no matter what org I try to connect to local host simply never responds.

After a very long timeout the error in the browser is:

> This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect. Try:
>
> Checking the connection Checking the proxy and the firewall
> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I've tried killing the server starting on 1717, but that just has the expected effect of telling vscode the operation was cancelled.   I have also tried rebooting.

I've run an strace, of course started mid process.  The process started on port 1717 is simply waiting for input, forever.

This is on Fedora 33.  The only things that happened since last it worked was a "dnf update -y".

Of course the firewall does not block localhost, but I added port 1717 to the list of open ports for firewalld just incase.